Cryptomatte from Blender to Nuke using custom fileout not working
my 3d scene :

In the render layer, I turn on Cryptomatte for object and material and this is my setup in the compositor (I render out the fileout node as CRIP02.exr - multilayer EXR) :

I also save render result from image editor as CRIP01.exr :

Both CRIP01.exr and CRIP02.exr are multilyer EXR, the difference is the CRIP01 is saved using default naming via 'save as' in image editor - while CRIP02 using custom name for the cryptomatte channels via compositor.
When I import them into Nuke , the CRIP01 (default names) works fine while the CRIP02 gives me error. Inside Nuke , I connect them to cryptomatte nodes. This is what I got when using CRIP01 ( works as I expected) :

And I got error when using CRIP02 - It doesn't display correctly and also the selected Names showing the weird naming :

Does anyone know what the problem is ? and how to fix it ?
Is this a bug? I'm using 4.1.1
blend file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PYkEGV6-9UzV6pR2lJg1N-ljpPnIt2r_/view?usp=sharing

This issue should be fixed in 4.2 if you haven't updated to it yet.
Note that 4.2 has a bug with the new GPU compositor that completely breaks the cryptos output from the compositor, only CPU mode works. You can track my bug report here

